# cygwin gcc 4.7+ in Eclipse CDT updating from 3.4

Tags: eclipse, gcc, g++, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I've followed the steps on the Cygwin wiki for updating my version of gcc. Now I have two installations of gcc in Cygwin: 3.4 in /bin and 4.7 in /usr/local/bin. Now, in Eclipse the only way to use it seems to be changing the invocation command from g++ to C:/cygwin/usr/local/bin/g++, and this has to be done for all projects. Is there any way to make Eclipse CDT use this by default? I have changed the Path environment variable, and typing g++ --version in a command line gives 4.7, but building a project in Eclipse with --version still gives 3.4

Comment: The problem was that Eclipse automatically adds "C:\cygwin\bin" to the start of your path variable when you choose the Cygwin GCC toolchain for a new project. Couldn't find a way to disable that, ended up just uninstalling cygwin and using mingw instead.